# Вызов хранимых процедур в Code First

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Добрый вечер! Использую Entity Framework Code First.
Создал хранимую процедуру через SQL Server Object Explorer.
Как мне теперь ее вызвать через контекст?

Ранее, когда использовал DB First, хранимую процедуру мог вызвать через контекст как обычный метод. Как добиться этого используя Code first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работу с хранимыми процедурами в подходе Code First нужно организовывать вручную. Для этого используются методы [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) - для выполнения запроса, возвращающего данные, - или [`ExecuteSqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx) - для выполнения команды.

Например, чтобы вызвать хранимую процедуру `GetPeople` с параметром `Age`, которая возвращает список людей определённого возраста, нужно создать класс-модель, который будет принимать данные (или использовать уже существующий класс, если он подходит):

```cs
public class PersonInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // другие необходимые свойства
}
```

Теперь вызвать хранимку можно следующим образом:

```cs
string sql = @"GetPeople {0}";
var people = context.Database.SqlQuery<PersonInfo>(sql, 42);

foreach (var personInfo in people) { ... }
```

Конечно, для удобного использования можно определить метод в классе контекста:

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbRawSqlQuery<PersonInfo> GetPeople(int age)
    {
        var sql = @"GetPeople {0}";
        return Database.SqlQuery<PersonInfo>(sql, age);
    }
}
```

После этого можно вызывать хранимую процедуру следующим образом:

```cs
var people = context.GetPeople(42);
```